# Paste commands into vim

Tags: vim, vi

Say I have a series of commands that I want to run in vim:

```
ifoo<ESC>:%s:foo:bar:g<CR>
```

When I paste the above into vim, this will be the output:

```
foo<ESC>:%s:foo:bar:g<CR>
```

How can I paste the above into vim so that my result becomes:

```
bar
```

I.e. that it treats `<ESC>` and `<CR>` et al as buttons instead of just characters part of a string.

Comment: If you want to do the same series of commands multiple times you should take a look at macros.

Comment: Well, don't paste them, *type* them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:exe "norm ifoo\<ESC>:%s:foo:bar:g\<CR>"
```

If I copy that line, open a new Vim document, and paste, that line appears in the command line (bottom of the screen). Then, when I hit Enter...

```
bar
```

...appears in the text document.

---

So, here's what's happening:

The colon ":" activates the command line, and "**exe**" (short for the command `execute`) instructs Vim to evaluate the following quoted string as Vimscript.

The string starts with the command "**norm**" (short for the command `normal`), which instructs Vim to treat the following text as if it were typed into Vim.

Another thing that is necessary is to escape the non-printing key identifiers (`<ESC>` and `<CR>`) with a backslash `\` so they are interpreted as their respective keystrokes and not as the literal characters.

Comment: Awesome! And thanks for the explanation. Registers also count as non-printing keys so they need to be escaped as well. I.e. \"xyy